# Eclipse Java classtype colors not working

Tags: eclipse, colors, syntax-highlighting

I'm still new the eclipse editor and am having some problems.

For some reason the Datatype/Classes/whatever always stay the same color and style as the default text chosen. This makes it incredibly difficult to get a good first glance view of my code.
I still get Tooltips and can ctrl-click the Datatypes to find the originating class etc, so the linkage still works as it should, just not the colors...

Anybody know how to fix this?

I am using the following version:
    Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
    Version: Kepler Service Release 1
    Build id: 20130919-0819

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Wgr.png

Comment: In your screenshot you show the Java Preferences but the editor open is on a .groovy file. I don't think the Java Editor preferences all apply to the Groovy editor.

Comment: Try right click on file and write here what is selected for `Open With` option...

Comment: It says Java Editor. I think I might have bound that manually a couple of weeks ago. And I don't find any specific "Groovy Editor" under "Other...". http://i.imgur.com/o1RZPMc.png